# How to update data in database using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want to update data in a database using values from datagridview but I have not succeeded. My aim is to search through my datagrid view and if my product name exist in gridview, then I update the quantity.

```
if (bunifuDataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in bunifuDataGridView1.Rows)
    {
       if (Convert.ToString(row.Cells[2].Value) == bunifuTextBox11.Text)
        {
            row.Cells[5].Value = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(bunifuTextBox10.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[5].Value));
            found = true;

            obj5.ProductName = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[2].Value);
            obj5.CostPricePerProduct = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[3].Value);
            obj5.SellingPricePerProduct = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[4].Value);
            obj5.Quantity = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[5].Value);
            obj5.ExpiryDate = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[6].Value);
            obj5.ProductNumber = Convert.ToInt32(obj2.ProductNumber);
            obj5.Quantity = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[5].Value);

            context.Entry.state = Entrystate.modified;

            context.SaveChanges();

            inboundgoods();
            refreshcustomergrid();
        }
    }

    if (!found)
    {
        inboundgoods();
    }
}
else
{
    inboundgoods();
}
```

I wish for my code to be able to search through datagridview for product name, and if there is a match, it should update that record by incrementing the stock quantity and save in stock database.

Answer (score 0):

This is hard to debug without having the full app in front of us, but we can recommend some code changes that will assist with debugging:

```
if (bunifuDataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in bunifuDataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        // Compare the Product on each row, add a watch to this value to assist debugging
        var product = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[2].Value);
        if (product == bunifuTextBox11.Text) // consider rename bunfuTextBox11 to something meaningful, like 'ProductNameTextBox'
        {
            row.Cells[5].Value = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(bunifuTextBox10.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[5].Value)); // consider rename bunifuTextBox10 to something more meaningful like 'ProductQuantityTextBox'
            found = true;
            obj5.ProductName = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[2].Value);
            obj5.CostPricePerProduct = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[3].Value);
            obj5.SellingPricePerProduct = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[4].Value);
            obj5.Quantity= Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[5].Value);
            obj5.ExpiraryDate = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[6].Value);
            obj5.ProductNumber = Convert.ToInt32(obj2.ProductNumber);
            obj5.Quantity = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[5].Value);
            //context.Entry.state=Entrystate.modified;
            // If your context has automatic change tracking enabled, this following line is not necessary
            // But you need to make sure you are setting the State on the correct object tracker instance by passing it in to the Entry method.
            var dbEntry = g.Entry(obj5);            
            if (dbEntry.State == EntryState.Detached)
                dbEntry.State = EntryState.Added;
            else
                dbEntry.State = EntryState.Modified;
            context.SaveChanges();
            inboundgoods();
            refreshcustomergrid();
        }
    }

    if (!found)
    {
        inboundgoods();
    }
}

else
{
    inboundgoods();
}
```

If you are not getting to the `found = true;` line of code during debugging then review your comparison logic, look for spelling and whitespace issues, you may want to change the comparison to something like this if your inputs or stored data might have blank spaces or inconsistent letter casing.

```
if (product.Trim().Equals(bunifuTextBox11.Text.Trim(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
```

> Take the time to use meaningful names for your data entry field controls, it will make you code easier to read and understand, especially when you post code examples to forums like SO!

Comment: my main aim with this app was to make an inventory system in which stock quantity will increase when i buy a product which already exist in stock and reduce when i sell.i am using entityframework

Comment: and when i do that,i get this error: Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded.

Comment: It is unclear where `obj5` is initialised from. You really need to provide more code, even if you check this into a GitHub repo i'm happy to help more. These errors suggest you have created `obj5` manually rather than loading it from the database, I have modified my solution to cater for that scenario, you will see if the current state is `Detached` then the State is changed to `Inserted`,   (detached would indicate that the object did not originate from the same data context)